# What is the cleanest way to ensure a set of values are all unique?

Tags: c#, logic

Let's say I have five integer values that must all be unique.

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;
int e;
```

Obviously I could do something like this to test for that:

```
if (a == b) {
    return false;
} else if (a == c) {
    return false;
} else if (a == d) {
    return false;
}
//etc etc
```

But that makes for extremely messy code in my opinion. Is there a "cleaner" way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a bit of overhead, but you could do:

```
new [] {a, b, c, d, e}.Distinct().Count() == 5
```

Comment: For a small set of variables I'm sure the overhead of `Distinct`ing and then counting is negligible.

Answer (score 6):

You can put all values in a set, and make sure that the set's cardinality equals the number of values that you put in:

```
ISet<int> vals = new HashSet<int> {
    a, b, c, d, e
};
if (vals.Count != 5) {
    Console.WriteLine("All values must be unique");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<int>() list = new List<int>(){a,b,c,d,e};

bool unique = list.Count() == list.Distinct().Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but you could also make a helper method like this:

```
static bool AreDistinct<T>(params T[] vals)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < vals.Length - 1; i++)
        for(int j = i + 1; j < vals.Length; j++)
            if(vals[i].Equals(vals[j]))
                return false;

    return true;
}
```

And call it like:

```
AreDistinct(a, b, c, d, e)
```

Comment: +1 neat code - I was kind of thinking along these lines when I made the question but I think it would be overkill in my specific situation.

Comment: The good thing about this one is it's reusable, buryable in a Utilities class, and self-documenting at the point you call it. Down side is you do have to put it somewhere.

Comment: @Ic Indeed. I'll definitely use it in the future - but your other answer suits me fine for this particular project - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> elements = new List<int>(){a,b,c,d,e};
if (elements.Distinct().Count() == elements.Count)
{
    //all elements are different
}
else
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only comparing two values at a time, you will have (n-1)! comparisons.

You should really consider Ic.'s answer. He offsets j by +1 the value of i to avoid redundant comparisons. That is as terse and efficient as it gets.

However, if you must write out the comparisons:

```
if (a == b || a == c || a == d || a == e)
    return false;

if (b == c || b == d || b == e)
    return false;

//etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleanness might be controversial, but if you sort them then (as needed) compare each adjacent pair you're in (n lg n) rather than (n^2).